# Stack Little endian addresses offsets

Tags: gdb, stack

I'm trying to understand how addresses work  in memory.

For example I have this stack : 
[image: es]

lets say we want to get the address of the 'a' character.

would it be in address 0xbffffc6c ? or did I get it absolutely wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct:

- the hexadecimal representation of data is always most significant bits first
- in little endian, the most significant bits are stored in the highest memory address

PS. The wikipedia article on endianess has some images that show this quite well for whenever I mix these up in my head.